# There are no Installations for NodeJS in Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, continuous-integration, protractor

Can't figure this out for quite a piece of time. Can't find answer on the web either.

My CI tool is Jenkins. Source of code is Git. A build trigger is another build stability. Plugin manager says that NodeJS is installed.

Now this above is building until I pick this build environment:

```
Provide Node & npm bin/ folder to PATH
```

(to use npm command) which shows me a dropdown list with Installations which has no Installations at all to choose from.

I can save this job and run it. In the output console I get:

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NodeJS Installation not found :
```

In global tool configuration there are no NodeJS installations. I guess this is the problem. Now, how can I know what Installation directory should I put there?

Answer (score 18):

Did you install and follow the instruction of the [node.js plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin)? It is quite straight forward:

> 1. After installing the plugin, go to the global jenkins configuration
>    panel (JENKINS_HOME/configure or JENKINS_HOME/configureTools if
>    using jenkins 2), and add new NodeJS installations For every Nodejs
>    installation, you can choose to install some global npm packages.
> 2. Now, go to a job configuration screen, you will have 2 new items :
>    On the "Build environnment" section, you will be able to pick one of
>    the NodeJS installations to provide its bin/ folder to the PATH.
>    This way, during shell build scripts, you will have some npm
>    executables available to the command line (like bower or grunt)

Comment: I did not install this. It was here before. I'm new in my current job and I found it like this. A guy in the company says that it seems that Jenkins is trying to call job with use of nodejs on a server where there is no nodejs.

Comment: followed those steps perfectly from the plugin page and it's still pulling up as not found. Got here by looking for a solution.

Comment: Found the solution! You have to goto "/pluginManager/advanced" and run "check now" so that it will check the nodejs site and do the global install. Kind of dumb..but yup.. :P

Comment: It is straightforward if the section appears in the configuration panel. When I installed the plugin it did not appear anywhere. I restarted Jenkins.